# Boostrap and maximum cell widths

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">Description MKT</div>
        <div class="col-lg-11">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At 1754 pixel screen width "Description MKT" does not wrap. But at 1697px width there is a line break between "Description" and "MKT". I can make the columns col-lg-2 and col-lg-10 which looks good at the smaller end of the "large" scale resolution, but at 1700+ screen pixel width the first column is far too wide.

Is there an easy way to lay out columns in bootstrap so you don't get too much whitespace? Ideally I need a max-width on columns without breaking bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-auto` on the first one, and `col` on the second.

This should make the first column only take the needed width, and the second take the rest of the row.

*Example:*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto bg-danger">Description MKT</div>
    <div class="col bg-success">
      Some other content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I've two rows though I want the first column to be the same width. Would that still work? I tried your suggestion, the first column ends up being about triple the width it needs to be to hold its contents.

Comment: My mistake, the first column stretches to fill the parent, forcing the second column onto the next row.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I removed `lg` from the classes, as they only apply for the `lg` viewport and **nothing under** that. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Same issue, the first column is 100% width. Using Chrome. I should note that my second column contains 3 rows.

Comment: Have you tried running the code snippet in this code? Does it work? What's your Bootstrap version? Does [this](http://jsbin.com/bocepuduri/edit?html,output) example work?

Comment: It seems to work as-is, EXCEPT, if there are multiple rows I need all column 1s to be the same width. I think I'll just use a form layout and right-align the label column (which I don't really like doing).

Comment: You can use [this](http://jsbin.com/latatalahu/edit?html,output). Ok if you just have static content, but may be a bit annoying if you are going to create the content dynamically.